# Code First from database with existing Designer from database

Tags: entity-framework

We've been working for along time using EF Designer from database, so switching to another approach is not an option for us.
Due to a legacy version of our app i need to create relationship between tables on EF level for the current version, so those relationships don't exist in the schema.
I understand that i can do do that using Code First from database approach, but the problem how do i map the fields and make these entities part of the main datacontext which we already extended its functionalities using another partial class.. the main problem now is just mapping the new entities fields 
i can't create OnCreatingModel in a new datacontext class since it does exist in the auto generated datacontext class.

to sum up.. is there anyway to use both approaches on the same DAL? taking in mind modifying auto-generated classes is absolutely not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add new associations in the edmx designer.